# Label legend interval with number of elements in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, legend

I have made a series of [choropleth maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) in ArcMap 10.
When I classify the interval the bottom of the dialogue tells how many elements are in the class.

Is it possible to have this number automatically places beside my class labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities that I can come up with:

1. Use the script at this [ESRI Forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=989&t=184661); OR
2. Copy the numbers in the *count column* and manually paste them over to the *label column* when you define & tweak your symbology categories (as shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Add Count to Legend]

In [layout view](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000043q000000), open the [legend properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000023000000) and browse to the Items tab (see above picture) where you can specify which items show the count.

If you were asking specifically about showing the count in the Table of Contents, I'm not sure how this can be done. I looked around but only found [this helpfile from ArcMAP](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000000p000000) that states

> For example, you can use tags in dynamic label expressions, annotation, legend text, map titles, and in the values of fields used to label features. Tags aren't resolved by the ArcMap table of contents, Table window, or Identify Results window, so tags added to field values will be visible as tags in those windows.

Comment: If you are looking for a utility to update feature counts on the TOC, take a look at [Is there a way to show a layers feature count in the TOC?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72006/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-layers-feature-count-in-the-toc).

Comment: Slick @RyanDalton

Answer (score 0):

This is an out-of-the-box feature of [legends](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-legends.htm) in ArcGIS for Desktop (since about 10.1):

> You can also add feature counts to your legend by checking the **Show feature count** check box.

It works well when Data Driven Pages are enabled.