# Show distinct features count as label in ArcMap10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling

How to show features count and not the value as a label in ArcMap10.2?

I have a polygon layer which contains 100 or so features. All the features are grouped by a `group_name` field containing values like "Forest", "Park", "Factory", etc.

I want to show the number of records present under a group. Suppose two features contains "Park", four features contain "Forest" in the `group_name`, so the label should be 2 on those features which contain "Park" and 4 on those features which contains "Forest".

EDIT:
The approach should be dynamic, so that, if some feature added/deleted then layer must reflect the difference. Like, if someone add an other feature and added a `group_name`= "Park" (in Attribute Table). Then the label should be automatically show 3 on map. I'm not concerned with TOC as such because I want to set the label expression and then I will publish it. The application users can add or delete the feature and they want to see the number of records as feature's label.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to adding a field to your attribute table is to use the legend to show your feature count.

If you symbolize your polygons by `group_name`and create a legend to show these there is an option to show feature count:

[image: Feature count]

This will then display in your legend as:

Forest (4)

Park (2)
etc...

Comment: I got this solution posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109120/27491

Answer (score 0):

You could add another field to your attribute table called `count` and for each row put the total. It's probably easiest to do manually using the select by attributes function select all "Forest" records and then calculate the `count` field to equal 4. Then repeating for each `group_name`type

Then it's pretty simple to use this field for your labels.

Comment: I can't add extra field just to show label and the approach should by dynamic. In the end, the users going to add or delete the records.